# Renaming variables stored using %store magic command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have few variables stored using the %store magic command of jupyter notebook.
I'd like to rename the variables which are stored.

I know I can create a new variable and delete the old one like this:

```
%store -r img_path
image_path = img_path
%store image_path
%store -d img_path
```

But it feels inefficient. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Assuming you aren't doing this repeatedly in a loop, you shouldn't worry about efficiency.  Anyways, I don't see anything in the help for that magic that looks like would preform a rename.  But you could spend a while reading the `%store` code and see if there is some loop hole!  :)

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I wouldn't be using a for loop. What I meant by being inefficient is that if have many variables to rename, this method could be very time consuming.

Comment: I haven't used `%store` much, but it looks like you have to use it separately for each variable you want to save.  I can't store several variables with one call.  It you have a lot to save, it might be better to save a list or dictionary, rather than a whole lot of variables.  It is indeed light weight.

Comment: okay. Thank you :}